# How to import a CSS table using BeautifulSoup when the table is a JSON object?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to import a table from a url that is CSS heavy using BS4. Here is my code:

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as ur

outfile = open(r"table_data.csv","w+",newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)

html = ur.urlopen('url')

tree = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")

table_tag = tree.select(playersData)[0]
tab_data = [[item.text for item in row_data.select("th,td")]
                for row_data in table_tag.select("tr")]

for data in tab_data:
    writer.writerow(data)
    print(' '.join(data))
```

The relevant part of the `tree`variable looks something like this:

```
<div class="block">
<div class="block-content">
<div class="players" data-countinpage="10" data-pagination="true" id="league-players"></div>
<script>
        var playersData = JSON.parse('\x5B\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x221250\x22,\x22player_name\x22\x3A\x22Mohamed\x20Salah\x22,\x22games\x22\x3A\x2235\x22,\x22time\x22\x3A\x222869\x227D');
</script> </div>
</div>
```

How do I import the `playersData`into a csv?

Answer (score 0):

One way to export the table into a csv would be:

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# import urllib.request as ur
import re
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

# Open output file for writing
outfile = open(r"table_data.csv","w")

# HTML string
# html = ur.urlopen('url')
html = """
<div class="block">
<div class="block-content">
<div class="players" data-countinpage="10" data-pagination="true" id="league-players"></div>
<script>
        var playersData = JSON.parse('\x5B\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x221250\x22,\x22player_name\x22\x3A\x22Mohamed\x20Salah\x22,\x22games\x22\x3A\x2235\x22,\x22time\x22\x3A\x222869\x22\x7D\x5D');
</script> </div>
</div>
"""

# Extract json string
tree = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
data = tree.find_all("script")[0].string
pattern = re.compile('var playersData = JSON.parse\(\'(.*)\'\);')
match = pattern.search(data)
json_obj = json.loads(match.group(1), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)

# Write header
keys = '"' + '","'.join(json_obj[0].keys()) + '"' + "\n"
outfile.write(keys)

# Write data  
for element in json_obj:
    values = '"' + '","'.join(element.values()) + '"' + "\n"
    outfile.write(values)
```

This code extracts the data from the script tag and parses the json string. It first outputs the header into the csv file. It then outputs each record into a separate row into the csv file.

When the program is run, the csv file will have this output:

```
"id","player_name","games","time"
"1250","Mohamed Salah","35","2869"
```

Note: The above code was tested using python version 2.7.10.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, it gives me the following error: 
json_obj = json.loads(match.group(1), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: That probably means that `pattern.search(data)` did not find any matches. Did you use the above code as it is or did you change the html string?

Comment: I had to change the html, but I made sure that my data variable would have the same value as yours and is a string variable---
`var playersData = JSON.parse('\x5B\x7B\x22id\...`

Comment: I think most likely the pattern didn't match the new html because even slight changes matter. If you can post the updated html, I'll update the pattern so that it matches.

Comment: in python 3.6, json_obj is giving JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)